# Web service callout failed: Unexpected element. Parser was expecting element 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/:Envelope' but found ':HTML'

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, salesforce, apex

while make a webservice call out I am getting below error:

Web service callout failed: Unexpected element. Parser was expecting element 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/:Envelope' but found ':HTML'

Please see below code which I am trying for this:

> > public class TestUtility_Cls{
>
> ```
> public list<Test_webService.KeyValuePair> IOG_pair = new list<Test_webService.KeyValuePair>();
> public pageReference calltestServices(){
>
>     I_pair = new list<Test_webService.KeyValuePair>();
>     Test_webService.webPort bindobj = new Test_Iwebervice.RtPort();
>         bindobj.clientCertName_x = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
>         bindobj.timeout_x = 120000;
>         bindobj.inputHttpHeaders_x = new Map<String, String>();
>         bindobj.inputHttpHeaders_x.put('Authorization', 'xxxxxxxxx');        
>
>     Test_webService.KeyValuePair I_KeyValue = new Test_webService.KeyValuePair();
>         I_KeyValue.key = 'SessionId';
>         I_KeyValue.value = 'Carrie09';
>         I_pair.add(I_KeyValue);
>
>         I_KeyValue = new Test_webService.KeyValuePair();
>         I_KeyValue.key = 'CR';
>         I_KeyValue.value = 'ExOffer';
>         I_pair.add(I_KeyValue);
>
>         Test_webService.ArrayOfKeyValuePair kevapair = new Test_webService.ArrayOfKeyValuePair();
>         kevapair.attribute = I_pair;
>
>         Test_webService.ProcessEventResponse_element IResp = new Test_webService.ProcessEventResponse_element();
>         IResp = bindingobj.ProcessEvent('QA', 'GetOffers', kevapair);
>
>     return null;    
> }
>
> }
> ```

Here I am using WSDL generated class's method.

Can someone help on this. How to resolve it?
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

```
public pageReference calltestServices(){
```

I think above method refers a html page reference from which you are extracting your input data.You are forming your input request in html format while your webservice is expectng soap envelope. I think you need to wrap or convet or edit your request, formed in above method as soap envelope, then only your server accept it.